# Do you know a css framework like Clever CSS?

Tags: css, frameworks

I found some time ago a CSS framework like Clever CSS but I don't remember its name and I can't find it now.

Do you know CSS Frameworks like Clever CSS? It was like Clever CSS, but more powerful.

Thanks.

EDIT: I have just realized it is actually a css *preprocessor*, it is like **Less CSS** too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resembles [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) somewhat:

```
table.hl
  margin: 2em 0
  td.ln
    text-align: right

li
  font:
    family: serif
    weight: bold
    size: 1.2em
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many

check this link, here is a nice review of most popular frameworks

http://speckyboy.com/2008/03/28/top-12-css-frameworks-and-how-to-understand-them/

I have used Elements and it is very powerful

http://elements.projectdesigns.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of the "Top 12 CSS Frameworks" [here](http://speckyboy.com/2008/03/28/top-12-css-frameworks-and-how-to-understand-them/), is it one of those?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/).